# SQL - Name missing but it's not

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I built this query based on other posts here in SO.

```
Declare @DatePeriod datetime

Set @DatePeriod = '2019-07-30'

SELECT  CustomSpecializationName,
        IsNull([1],0) as 'Week 1',
        IsNull([2],0) as 'Week 2',
        IsNull([3],0) as 'Week 3',
        IsNull([4],0) as 'Week 4',
        IsNull([5], 0) as 'Week 5'

FROM 
(
    SELECT  
        cs.CustomSpecializationName
        ,DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, r.MedicalReviewDate), 0), r.MedicalReviewDate) +1 as [Weeks]
    From Referral r
      LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomSpecialization cs ON cs.CustomSpecializationID = r.CustomSpecializationID
    WHERE 1=1
    AND DatePart(Month, r.MedicalReviewDate)= DatePart(Month, @DatePeriod )
    AND DatePart(Year, r.MedicalReviewDate)= DatePart(Year, @DatePeriod )
)p
    Pivot (COUNT(CustomSpecializationName) for Weeks in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) as pv
```

The issue is that when I am trying to run this - SQL Profiler is telling me the the CustomSpecializationName is missing.....Not sure what I am missing?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: What do you mean it's missing? Do you see a `NULL` value in the result set? Do you get this in addition to the expected results or only `NULL` values?

Comment: Include the full error in your question. Show the definitions of all tables referenced.

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'CustomSpecializationName'. Is the exact error

Comment: bendataclear - It will not run at all - I get the error I posted above

Comment: I am using the latest Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this query:

```
Declare @DatePeriod datetime

Set @DatePeriod = '2019-07-30'

    SELECT   
            IsNull([1],0) as 'Week 1',
            IsNull([2],0) as 'Week 2',
            IsNull([3],0) as 'Week 3',
            IsNull([4],0) as 'Week 4',
            IsNull([5], 0) as 'Week 5'

    FROM 
    (
        SELECT  
            cs.CustomSpecializationName
            ,DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, r.MedicalReviewDate), 0), r.MedicalReviewDate) +1 as [Weeks]
        From Referral r
          LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomSpecialization cs ON cs.CustomSpecializationID = r.CustomSpecializationID
        WHERE 1=1
        AND DatePart(Month, r.MedicalReviewDate)= DatePart(Month, @DatePeriod )
        AND DatePart(Year, r.MedicalReviewDate)= DatePart(Year, @DatePeriod )
    )p
        Pivot (COUNT(CustomSpecializationName) for Weeks in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) as pv
```

It should work.

You are already using that column as "column being aggregated" in the pivoted columns 'Week 1' ... 'Week n'

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15